# How to add multiple CA certificates to LDAP client

Tags: linux, ldap

I'm having trouble with adding a 2nd LDAP server into the client configuration. If I configure the client to use just either one, it works fine. So I'm sure both CA certificates work.

I have tried using TLS_CACERT option in both `/etc/pam_ldap.conf` and `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`, but it doesn't work. I get this error when I do an ldapsearch.

This is what I have currently configured.

```
uri ldaps://ldap.abc.com:636/
ssl no
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
pam_password md5
```

The CA certificate in `/etc/openldap/cacerts` has been hashed by using openssl.  I also tried adding a 2nd hash sym link with .1 at the end but no luck.

Comment: What error? (You didn't actually post yours.)

Comment: any luck? I am also trying the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple ldap servers, sign the cert for all the LDAP servers with the same cacert. That way you only have to distribute only one cacert.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by adding a Classic Load Balancer above both LDAP Servers and terminating the SSL to CLB itself.